# new domain keeps timing out

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

i have added ip-based virtual host, restarted apache.

i have also added A dns record to my new domain to point to a new ip on my dedicated server.

however, when i try navigating to http://mynewip

it says connection timed out.

i believe its something to do with firewall. ? how can i edit iptables ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the new IP in the server?

Run 'ip addr' in the server and make sure lists the new IP. If it doesn't, add it to /etc/network/interfaces as a virtual interface (eth0:0) and then bring it up using 'ifup eth0:0 up'.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Also use `iptables-save` to see what firewall rules you may have.